# Nokia lumia930 phone dont start

Tags: nokia-lumia-930

My Nokia lumia930 dont start and i need to backup the phone before I reset the phone to the factory default settings. It switch on and off, without starting my windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

If the phone does not start, you can't backup any files without opening up the device and somehow accessing the internal memory.

You can check if your phone hasn't made any backups already here: https://onedrive.live.com/options/DeviceBackups

Also, if you're using a Microsoft Account your photos should have been uploaded to OneDrive and your contacts and calendards should be synced on Outlook.com as well.